# How to sum the frist index in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

How to sum the first index of array with the number of iterations the max number iteration is 2.

I've tried use below code, but I still get wrong result for index number 2.

```
a = np.array([[858,833,123],
[323,542,927],
[938,361,271],
[679,272,451]])

max_iter = 2
for i in range(max_iter):
    for j in range(len(a)):
        a[j][0] += i
```

the results from the code above :

```
[[859 833 123]
 [324 542 927]
 [939 361 271]
 [680 272 451]]
```

my expected results is:

```
[859,833,123],
[325,542,927],
[939,361,271],
[681,272,451]
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what operation you're trying to perform. "sum the first index of array with the number of iterations" doesn't make sense, and doesn't sound anything like any sort of operation that would produce your expected output. I can't think of any reasonable operation that *would* produce that output.

Comment: I guess the 1st value of last row should be `681`. But still, the description is vague. Could you have an array with uneven number of rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not clear about requirements, i just take a guess that you want to add a number in range `(1, max_iterator)` to rows in order, for example:

- add 1 to row 1st
- add 2 to row 2nd
- add 1 to row 3rd
- add 2 to row 4th
- and 1 to row 5th
- and so on

If so, you can do it by following:

```
a = np.array([[858,833,123],
             [323,542,927],
             [938,361,271],
             [679,272,451]])
max_iter = 2
iter = 0
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i][0] = a[i][0] + (iter % max_iter) + 1
    iter += 1
print(a)
```

Output will be as expected:

```
[859,833,123],
[325,542,927],
[939,361,271],
[681,272,451]
```

Comment: how make it dynamic? so in the real case I will have 15000 datasets. I will make max iteration to 50.

Comment: Just set `max_iter` to 50 and enjoy.

Comment: @stackoffer make sure you are running my code, not of another one.

Comment: I've try it, but still wrng.you can see in this picture https://imgur.com/h4E3dh0

Answer (score 1):

#### You're almost there! You're just adding the wrong value.

The key problem is that you are continuously increasing `i`.
In reality (I think) you want to add 1 on the first row, 2 on the second, 1 on the third and 2 on the fourth.

Remember the row numbers are index from 1. Therefore you can do `% 2` so that the first row, #0, gives 0. You can add 1 to that, to give the increment you want, which is 1.

The second row, #1, gives 1; when you add 1, you get 2, which is the correct increment for that row.

The third row, #2, gives 0; when you add 1, you get 1, which is the correct increment for that row, and so on.

```
a = np.array([[858,833,123],
[323,542,927],
[938,361,271],
[679,272,451]])

max_iter = 2
for row in range(len(a)):
        increment = (row % max_iter) +1 
        a[row][0] += increment
```

Comment: how make it dynamic? so in the real case I will have 15000 datasets. I will make max iteration to 50.

Comment: change max_iter to 50, and it should work.

Comment: I've try but it will be wrong. you can see on this picture https://imgur.com/chdqC36

Comment: Hmmmm... Impossible to advise you without being able to see what is in FPData, immediately before those lines run.

Comment: u can try use this data arr = np.zeros((15000, 6))

Comment: Ah sorry, there was a typo in my code - I should have said _row_ % max_iter. I have corrected it now. Try, and let me know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252306/discussion-between-stack-offer-and-eureka).

Answer (score 0):

You can repeat 1 and 2 to `len(a)` size then add them to the first column of `arr`

```py
max_iter = 2
arr = [(i % max_iter)+1 for i in range(len(a))]
a[:, 0] += arr
```

```
$ print(arr)

[1, 2, 1, 2]

$ print(a)

[[859 833 123]
 [325 542 927]
 [939 361 271]
 [681 272 451]]
```